# Is the phrase "recall that..." an abuse?

Tags: soft-question, article-writing

I love how in some proofs delivered formally or informally, you would always encounter the phrase "recall that".

The irony here is that you precisely do not recall this notion or formula e.g. the polar form of the laplacian, that's why it needed to be brought up again.

What's the opinion from the math community on this?

Comment: If it's something that the reader has probably seen before, or very close to such, but forgotten, then I think it's not so bad. If it's used to sneak advanced or ill-known results into a piece of writing for people who are unlikely to have seen the result, I think it's a mistake.

Comment: "Recall that the last time we used the word 'clearly' it wasn't clear at all, hence why we shall now use the word 'obviously.'"

Comment: I think the point of such a statement is that "we already defined ..." so we are not going to define ... again.  It is more a hint that, if you don't remember what it means, you can flip back and retrieve the info.

Comment: @TravisJ I don't really agree-people seem to use this very frequently to recall things that aren't in the text, but rather are allegedly common knowledge to the readership.

Comment: @KevinCarlson, perhaps you are correct and I should amend my comment to say that "recall that" should mean it has previously been defined/discussed in this paper/text.  Perhaps too frequently this is not the case.  If they didn't define/discuss yet (and are leaving it out), then perhaps it would be better to say "the following is (well?) documented in literature" or some such phrase.

Comment: @TravisJ Eh, I'm not sure what "should" can usefully mean here. The fact is that people do use recall to recall background knowledge, and will probably continue to do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends. A lot of the time I see this, it's an ugly thing that I've seen but didn't remember the specifics. Your example about the Laplacian in polar coordinates is a good one. In these cases I read it as "hopefully you've seen this; here's a refresher; if you haven't seen it at all, go look it up elsewhere, because we won't be spending much time on it."

So this isn't so bad necessarily. Compare it to the extreme of terseness, which is to simply use the result in the middle of a proof without singling it out as something to be recalled. Yet we do this all the time with results that become routine, even when they are actually fairly sophisticated results. (Holder's inequality, for instance.)

So there is some balance to be struck. Some things need explanation in the text. Others need little to no explanation at all, being assumed as background material. In the middle, there are things that some readers might not already know, which should be singled out to avoid confusion, but that enough readers will already know that you shouldn't waste too much time on it.

The problem is when something which the reader thinks is in the first category gets lumped into the third category. Rarely does something the reader thinks is in the first category get lumped into the second category.

All of these things become much less irritating if a reference to a less advanced work is provided.

Comment: Nice answer, although according to your "Rarely..." sentence you live in a more beautiful world than I!

Comment: @KevinCarlson At least that sentence tends to be true for textbooks. Approaching the research literature is another matter...

Comment: Yes, that sounds about right.

Comment: I had occasion to use this phrase [today](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1184385/50776) when reminding readers about a general term that may not be so well-known. I agree that the general gist is "make sure you know what I'm talking about or look it up, 'cause I'm moving on", and it also helps give people an idea of the expected sophistication of the reader.